# Increment NSNumber in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, increment, nsnumber

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793181/how-to-increment-an-nsnumber), but there needs to be an easier way than that.

If I have an array of NSNumbers and I want to increment one of them, I have to do this?

```
[myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[(NSNumber *)[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] + 1]];
```

or

```
myArray = [myArray.mutableCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[(NSNumber *)[myArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] + 1]].copy;
```

if you decide to use an immutable array for some reason.

I know I could always just use an int array, but I was just curious if there was a simple way to do this.

Also, how should I define an int array if I need access to it either within an implementation or a full file (the entire .m) without making it global?

Would it just be as simple as throwing this at the top of my implementation / file?

```
static int *myInt;
```

Comment: I think this way is simple enough.

Comment: You can make it a little more concise by using @() instead of +numberWithInt:

Comment: @H2CO3 I guess I'm comparing it to a property or iVar incrementation of `myInt++`

Comment: ...and by not casting `id` to `NSNumber *`. The compiler will guess the type anyway from the selector name.

Comment: @Catfish_Man Yeah. I wanted to avoid writing literals in my question so I didn't potentially confuse anyone that found my question.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, yes, you need that many steps. With literals, it can be a little easier to read:

```
myMutableArray[index] = @( [ myMutableArray[index] intValue] + 1 ) ;
```

Your second code example won't work because `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` returns `void`, not the NSMutableArray it acted upon. You'd need to create a `mutableCopy` of the NSArray, then `replaceObject`, then set the NSArray to a `copy` of the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using C++ STL containers rather than creating a plain int array if you need to be able to resize it. Rename your implementation file's extension to `.mm` instead of `.m`.

```
std::vector<int> numbers = { 2, 4, 6 };
numbers[1]++; // { 2, 5, 6 }
```

Remember to include the container's definition.

```
#import <vector>
```

Comment: The reason I would use the vector is so that I don't have to deal with the malloc and free parts? For this situation, I don't need to resize the array, but just have free reign on changing the values. I would still be interested in knowing why the vector is better, if theres an actual performance increase, or whatnot.