# Numbers in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to setup a dictionary to have a string key with a numeric value (that needs to be incremented.

This is how I am initializing with value 1.

```
[person.list setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:name];
```

How would I go about incrementing the value as needed?

Comment: From my understanding, an NSDictionary can only hold objects as the value, wouldn't this prevent me from just typing numbers?

Comment: `@(number.intValue + 1)`, y'know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the object from the dictionary for the key, do the modification and then add that object to the dictionary for same key, this will replace previous object.

```
NSInteger number = [[dict objectForKey:name] integerValue];
number+=1;

[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:number] forKey:name];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sweet-ass category,

```
@interface NSNumber (NSNumber_Incrementing)    
-(NSNumber *)increment;    
@end

@implementation NSNumber (NSNumber_Incrementing)    
-(NSNumber *)increment {
     return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self intValue] + 1];
}


[person.list setObject:[mynumb increment] forKey:name];
```

that means you need to hold mynumb

Add a protocol for NSDecimal et al.

```
@protocol Incrementing
- (NSNumber *)increment;
@end
so the above might be
@interface NSNumber (NSNumber_Incrementing) <Incrementing>
...
@interface NSDecimableNumber (NSNumber_Incrementing) <Incrementing>
```

But even f*ng sweeter is a category on Dictionary:

```
@interface NSDictionary (NSDictionary_SweetIncrementing) 
    -(void) incrementNumberForKey:name;  
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (NSDictionary_SweetIncrementing) 
-(void) incrementNumberForKey:name throws NSNumberException {
         NSNumber numb = (NSNumber *)[self valueForKey: name];         
         return [self setValue: [numb increment] forKey: name];
}
@end
```

valueForKey and setValue belong to NSDictionary. You are using a NSMutableDictionary that offers objectForKey and setObject.... so do that instead if so desired.

Yeah. And add some exceptions for key not associated with number

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793181/how-to-increment-an-nsnumber)

Comment: `increment` makes it sound like the `NSNumber` itself is changing, which is impossible because it's not mutable. I'd change the method name to something else.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to use the category on dictionary though I'm, getting this error.  **Expected ':'** on the line -> throws NSNumberException.    I ended up just deleting throws NSNumberException and it works great.  Really nice way to make helpers in Objective C.  Just curious but why place this in the category -> (NSDictionary_SweetIncrementing)?

Answer (score 0):

If its sequential increment than a `static` `integer` will be helpful!

```
static int increment = 1;

[person.list setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:increment++] forKey:name];
```

If you're unaware of `static` variables, [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087061/objective-c-static-variables) question can be helpful.

Comment: I have many entries in the dictionary that could be in many different quantities.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but one solution could be

```
[person.list setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:person.list.count+1] forKey:name];
```

Comment: I don't need to know the current numbers of entries in the dictionary, my goal is to retrieve the current integer that is the value and increment it by 1.

Comment: @johnhannigan And what prevents you from that, seriously?

Comment: @johnhannigan **Are you serious?** I've been developing for iOS for 3 years. I know `NSDictionary` can hold Objective-C objects only, but this is so trivial I had a hard time understanding what your problem was at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSNumber *num = [person.list objectForKey:name];
    if(!num) [person.list setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:name];
    else [person.list setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:([num intValue]+1)] forKey:name];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure `person.list` is an instance of `NSMutableDictionary`. (Also might want to change the list property on person to a different name. List implies an Array-like structure rather than a Dictionary.)

You can use the new NSDictionary syntax and the primitive to object boxing. I'm assuming the number is an unsigned integer here.

```
person.list[name] = @([person.list[name] unsignedIntegerValue] + 1);
```

That is syntactically similar to (split into multiple lines for readability)

```
NSUInteger previous = [[person.list objectForKey:name] unsignedIntegerValue];
NSNumber *incremented = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:previous + 1];
[person.list setObject:incremented forKey:name];
```

The `@(...)` syntax converts a [primitive number to an NSNumber object](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). While the `[name]` syntax is shorthand for `setObject:forKey:` of `NSMutableDictionary`.